# Websockets don't work with Fiddler

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, fiddler

**Context**: I'm trying to debug a website using https://www.npmjs.org/package/webkit-devtools-agent , which uses the Chrome debugger. Furthermore, I want to embed the debug page in an `<iframe>`, so that I can write client-side javascript to parse the output in ways not officially available. To get round the same-origin restriction on the iframe, I plan to use fiddler to trick the browser into thinking everything is from the same domain.

When I open the page I get an error saying: "Detached from the target. Remote debugging has been terminated with reason: websocket_closed. Please re-attach to the new target."

This happens if the "Capture Traffic" option is selected in Fiddler, even if I just access the debug page directly with no aliasing and without actually using Fiddler.

After it fails, the websocket is broken and I have to restart the webkit-devtools-agent service.

I'm using Fiddler v2.4.9.4 and Chrome v37.0.2062.120m.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved: It turns out my proxy settings in Fiddler were out of date (Tools -> Fiddler Options -> Gateway).